# Terraform plan error with github actions for proxmox

Tags: terraform, github-actions, proxmox

I tried Terraform with Proxmox and it's working fine. Trying to learn and utilize the GitHub action feature with self-hosted github runner

```
name: LCX_2
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
env:
  PM_API_URL: ${{ secrets.PM_API_URL }}
  PM_API_TOKEN_ID: ${{ secrets.PM_API_TOKEN_ID }}
  PM_API_TOKEN_SECRET: ${{ secrets.PM_API_TOKEN_SECRET }}
  ROOT_CT_PASSW: ${{ secrets.ROOT_CT_PASSW }}
  PM_TLS_INSECURE: ${{ secrets.PM_TLS_INSECURE }}
jobs:
  terraform:
    runs-on: "self-hosted"
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3


      - name: Terraform Init
        id: init
        run: terraform init

      - name: Terraform Plan
        id: plan
        run: terraform plan -no-color
```

On plan, it's giving an error even though I have set the secrets in the repo. Can anyone guide or point out a reference, please

```
  with provider["registry.terraform.io/terraform-for-proxmox/proxmox"],
  on provider.tf line 12, in provider "proxmox":
  12:   pm_api_url = var.pm_api_url

Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning values in the shell environment for input to Terraform variables requires prefixing the key with `TF_VAR_`. There is a short section in the [documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#environment-variables) about this. Therefore the `env` keys in your GH Actions config file need a corresponding prefix. Also, there is a case typo in the keys where they are all uppercase whereas according to the error message the declared variable is lowercase:

```
env:
  TF_VAR_pm_api_url: ${{ secrets.PM_API_URL }}
  TF_VAR_pm_api_token_id: ${{ secrets.PM_API_TOKEN_ID }}
  TF_VAR_pm_api_token_secret: ${{ secrets.PM_API_TOKEN_SECRET }}
  TF_VAR_root_ct_passw: ${{ secrets.ROOT_CT_PASSW }}
  TF_VAR_pm_tls_insecure: ${{ secrets.PM_TLS_INSECURE }}
```

where I have assumed all environment variables map to declared Terraform input variables similar to the one presented in the error message because the declaration configs are absent from the question. Refrain from modifying any keys where this is not true.